# jquery change val of select if id has 3 periods

Tags: jquery, select, selector

I am trying to use javascript to change a value of a select box on a ToysRUs address page. The project is an extension that fills out an address form automatically. I get null trying to select the object in jquery even if I use backslashes.

The page is using jQuery  (typeof jQuery != 'undefined') is true

```
> <select id="billingAddress.address.stateSelect" class="stateSelect
> dataRequired fieldError" name="billingAddress.address.stateSelect"
> tabindex="1">
```

document.getElementById("billingAddress.address.stateSelect") // returns the element.

$("#billingAddress.address.stateSelect") // returns null.

I still get null after escaping the periods with backslashes.

```
s=document.getElementById("billingAddress.address.stateSelect").id;
console.log(s);
s= "#"+s.replace( /(:|\.|[|])/g, "\\$1" ); 
//also tried \\\\ backslashes and \\\ backslashes
console.log(s); //gives billingAddress\\.address\\.stateSelect
console.log($(s)); //is still null
```

I would like to use something like

$("#billingAddress.address.stateSelect").val("CA").change()

to change the element and trigger the change. Is this the correct way to change a jquery select?

The page can be seen by going to toysrus trying to purchase something and getting to the address page -- inspect element on the state select.

Comment: Do not use points, jquery search for an element with an id `billingAddress` and with two classes: `address` and `stateSelect`..

Comment: @Hackerman The ID actually contains those dots.

Comment: @Drew i know but i'm explaining how jquery plays this instruction:  `$("#billingAddress.address.stateSelect").val()`

Comment: [It does not show null for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/6bL4ar3z/)

Comment: And that is why it shows null....it's because of the id of the input....but if you try something like: `$("[id*=billingAddress]").val()` you get the right result

Comment: Everything gives back null, is there another reason jquery could be running but not functioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The periods are confusing the jQuery selector, which is looking for an element with an id of billingAddress, as well as a class of address, and another class of stateSelect.

To get around this, you can select your element like this:

```
$("select[id='billingAddress.address.stateSelect']");
```

And you can assign your value just like you were trying to do:

```
 $("select[id='billingAddress.address.stateSelect']").val("someValue");
```

Comment: Whoops, obviously you are using a select, not a div. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I am on the toysrus address page (see above to get there) and type in    javascript:alert($("select[id='billingAddress.address.stateSelect']")) and I still get null. I'm also on firefox on a mac. Seems like it should work but does not.

Comment: It appears that the prototype.js was also running and overriding the jquery syntax. All jquery attempts returned null.  $('billingAddress.address.stateSelect') returned the actual object. And I changed it with .setValue("CA") which is Prototype.js syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you want:

```
$('#billingAddress\\.address\\.stateSelect').//whatever
```

Comment: I get null with this as well as the other suggestions when I go to the toysrus address page and run from the address bar javascript:alert($('#billingAddress\\.address\\.stateSelect')). Could there be some other reason it says it is null?